# Remove email signature after sending single email with email template

Tags: email, email-template, singleemailmessage, template

here is the scenario.

UserA has email signature in his setting. 
When clicking on a custom button, a template email is sent out to Person_B with sender UserA's name. Now the sent out name has 2 email signatures. The email Person_B receives looks like below:

```
-------------------------------------------
|Templated content                         |
|                                          |
|User A                                    |
|Blabla                                    |
-------------------------------------------

User A
I'm the email signature text coming from setup-->Email setting
```

Requirement is to remove the `User A I'm the email signature text coming from setup-->Email setting`.

Any ideas appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

depending on how you are sending the email (eg. javascript, Apex Callout)  If you're using apex...

The `SingleEmailMessage` has the `Email` class as a parent class. Therefore you can use the method `setUseSignature(useSignature)` as outlined in the [Email Documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_email_outbound_base.htm). When set to `false` the Users signature will not be added to the email.

I'm not sure if you could use this from javascript or as a parameter in the `/EmailAuthor` Url but here is some info on [calling apex from a custom button](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000325250&type=1&mode=1)